# Include geom_segment in a legend in a separate group

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the line (`geom_segment`) appear in the legend as a separate item in its own group?
The legend should look like:

- Groups

  - g1
  - g2
- Info

  - mean

The minimal code:

```
data_points <- tibble(x = c(rep(1:10, 2)), y = rnorm(20), group = c(rep("g1", 10), rep("g2", 10)))
data_line <- tibble(x = 1:10, y = 0.5)

ggplot(data_points, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = data_line$x[1], xend = data_line$x[10], y = data_line$y[1], yend = data_line$y[10]), color = "black") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Groups", labels = c('g1', 'g2'), values = c('blue', 'red'))
```

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible add legend for geom\_point and geom\_segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281826/is-it-possible-add-legend-for-geom-point-and-geom-segment)

Comment: I saw this answer, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified from  [Is it possible add legend for geom_point and geom_segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281826/is-it-possible-add-legend-for-geom-point-and-geom-segment?answertab=active#tab-top).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
data_points <- tibble(x = c(rep(1:10, 2)), y = rnorm(20), group = c(rep("g1", 10), rep("g2", 10)))
data_line <- tibble(x = 1:10, y = 0.5)

ggplot(data_points, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = data_line$x[1], xend = data_line$x[10], 
        y = data_line$y[1], yend = data_line$y[10],
        linetype = "mean"), 
    color = "black") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Groups", labels = c('g1', 'g2'), values = c('blue', 'red')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Info", values = c("mean" = 1))
```

[image]

change the order of legends

```r
ggplot(data_points, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = data_line$x[1], xend = data_line$x[10], 
        y = data_line$y[1], yend = data_line$y[10],
        linetype = "mean"), 
    color = "black") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Groups", labels = c('g1', 'g2'), values = c('blue', 'red')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Info", values = c("mean" = 1)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 2), linetype = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted. I have one more problem, though. In my real data `Groups` and `Info` are swapped with each other. How to set the order of appearance?

Comment: use argument `order` to control the order the legend, and Ihave added the code in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you, @yang : )